# Searching particular files in the folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, fancybox

Hi I can search all the images with .jpg extension and pass it to the fancybox gallery , The issue is i just want the images of particular productid 
for instance if a product has 5 images , and they are saved as (productid_imagenumber.jpg) , therefore a product with productid 99 will be saved as 99_1.jpg , 99_2.jpg similarly 99_5.jpg,
I can pass the productID but i cant find a away just to get the images of that productID , instead of getting all the images which is done by the function below:

```
Dim directory As DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:Images\")
        Dim allImages() = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim strContent As String = ""
        For Each image As FileInfo In allImages

            Dim strTemp As String = (String.Format("<img  src=""{0}"" />", image.Name))
           strContent = "<a class=""fancybox-thumb"" rel=""fancybox-thumb1"" href=""" & image.Name + image.Extension & """ title="""">" & _
            "<img src=""" & image.Name + image.Extension & """ alt="" /></a>"
        Next

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strContent) Then
            Return String.Format("<div id=""product-lightbox""><p>{0}</p></div>", strContent)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If

    End Function
```

Can any one give any suggestion or assistance on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim images = (From img In directory.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              Where   img.Name.Contains("_") _
              AndAlso img.Name.Split("_"c)(0) = productID).ToList
```

Ok, you are using .NET 2.0:

```
Dim allProductIDImages As New List(Of IO.FileInfo)
For Each img As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If img.Name.Contains("_") Then
        Dim ID As String = img.Name.Split("_"c)(0)
        If ID.Equals(productID) Then
            allProductIDImages.Add(img)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Another - possibly faster - approach is to let [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) pre-search:

```
Dim pattern As String = String.Format("*{0}_*.jpg", productID)
Dim allProductIDImages() As IO.FileInfo = _
       directory.GetFiles(pattern, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: does this will find all the images of that productid , for instanct if i pass 100 , will it find all the images associated with the product id 100 which is 100_1.jpg , 100_2.jpg......

Comment: Try it out... yes it should. The first part is the productID(as string) and the second part the image-number(as string) and the query returns alls images as List(Of FileInfo).

Comment: will it return an array of all the images or should i define it as dim images()

Comment: sorry i cant use linq as i m using .net2 , cant find import system.linq :(

Comment: wont it be slow , as first it will get all the images as i have got many images , cant i just get images of id first then split

Comment: each product will have a maximum image of 6 so it wont exceed more then _6.jpg

Comment: sorry for bothering you but can i do a search like For Each img In directory.GetFiles(startwithproductid, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories), in this way it will get only the images which starts with that productid , instead of getting all the images thus the results will be faster

Comment: @Mra A: edited again to show you how to use a search-pattern.

Comment: Thanks thats great , i will test it now , also why do we not declare allProductIDImages as an array.

Comment: @Mr A: Because i've set [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) On by default. But i see that this is new in VS 2008. So you need to declare it in 2.0 explicitly. Changed it in answer.